# Alter table <table_name> reject limit unlimited returns invalid Alter table option?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the code:

```
alter table costs
    reject limit unlimited;
```

I'm trying to load something from Oracle object store to ADW using dbms_cloud.copy_data, but I keep getting this error: Reject limit reached. So I tried to alter the table to make the reject limit unlimited, but then I get 00000- "invalid alter table option" Cannot figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

`REJECT LIMIT` option is valid only for external tables. Is `costs` an external table? If not, well, it won't work.

---

As of the loading process and the error: perhaps it would help if you posted some more info - code itself, as well as the full error stack because I presume that it contains additional useful info.

Is it, by any chance, `ORA-20003: Reject limit reached`? If so, it probably tells which table to query to retrieve error details which might - in turn - help you fix the issue.

Comment: thanks for the comment, it's not an external table so that makes sense that it doesn't work. This is the code I'm trying to execute
```
begin
 dbms_cloud.copy_data(
    table_name =>'COSTS',
    credential_name =>'OBJADW1',
    file_uri_list =>'https://objectstorage.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloud.com/n/orasenatdoracledigital02/b/tutorial_load_adw/o/tutorial_adw_datacosts.dat',
    format => json_object('ignoremissingcolumns' value 'true', 'removequotes' value 'true')
 );
end;
```

Comment: Here is the full error it's giving me 
ORA-20003: Reject limit reached, query table "ADWC_USER"."COPY$57_LOG" for error details
ORA-06512: at "C##CLOUD$SERVICE.DBMS_CLOUD", line 968
ORA-06512: at "C##CLOUD$SERVICE.DBMS_CLOUD", line 2254
ORA-06512: at "C##CLOUD$SERVICE.DBMS_CLOUD", line 2277
ORA-06512: at line 2

Comment: As I said - query ADWC_USER.COPY$57_LOG and see what it contains.

Comment: @averagej63 It would be good to add those details to the question so everyone can see them easily without having to read comments on answers. This isn't a discussion forum.

Comment: @Littlefoot Issue's been resolved. I queried the log file like you said and it was a datetime format issue. Thank you for your help :)